# How to make radio button connected to a line in a text file and make it appear on the frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I have created a program which should allow users to choose a candidate that they would like to vote for. I have created the class on a separate python file but in the same folder and have used the import filename * statement. When I click on the button to vote for candidates, the radio buttons and the text do not appear on the frame.

```
class LoginSuccessful(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    label = tk.Label(self, text="Greenwich Student Union Voting System", bg="blue", fg="white",
                     width="200", height="2", font=controller.title_font)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

    button = tk.Button(self, text="View Candidates", height="2", width="30",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("ViewCandidates"))
    button.pack()

    label = tk.Label(self, text="", )
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Vote for Candidates", height="2", width="30",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("VoteForPresident"))
```

## The above code is in separate python file however I have linked the python files together using an import statement

```
class VoteForPresident(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Vote for your President ", bg="red", fg="white",
                     width="200", height="2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

    def selection(self):
        radio = IntVar()

        selection = msg.showinfo("Submit", "You have chosen President Barn as your preference " + str(radio.get()))

        with open("PresidentCandidates.txt", "r") as f:
            label = tk.Label(self, text=f.read())
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        r1 = Radiobutton(text="1ST PREFERENCE", variable=radio, value=1, command=selection)
        r1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        r2 = Radiobutton(text="2ND PREFERENCE", variable=radio, value=2, command=selection)
        r2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        r3 = Radiobutton(text="3RD PREFERENCE", variable=radio, value=3, command=selection)
        r3.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        r4 = Radiobutton(text="4TH PREFERENCE", variable=radio, value=4, command=selection)
        r4.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Back", height="2", width="30",
                       command=lambda: 
self.controller.show_frame("LoginSuccessful"))
    button.pack()
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of the code of class `VoteForPresident`.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation

Comment: According to your code, the function `selection()` has never been called.  So how do you expect the radiobuttons be shown?

Comment: how would i call the function?

Comment: And also where would I call it? Would I need to use self.controller.show statement?

Comment: As I do not know the whole design of your program, I have modified your code based on my understanding.  See [here](https://pastebin.com/nAzqgMRF).

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting errors. It doesn't seem to understand what the function is doing.